# push information to an array but at index 0

Tags: jquery, arrays

I want to push information to an array I have created. The thing is I want to push the info to be first in the array, or at index 0. How do I do this?

I want to avoid having to reverse the array to get the most recent first as this makes things much complicated later..

e.g, my array may look like:

```
{"entry1":"entry1-value"}, {"entry2":"entry2-value"}
```

and I want to push a new value to be first:

```
{"newEntry":"newEntry-value"},{"entry1":"entry1-value"},{"entry2":"entry2-value"}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `unshift()`:

```
array1.unshift({'newEntry' : 'newEntry-value'});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/RQFcC/).

References:

- [`unshift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift).

Answer (score 4):

`yourArray.unshift(newValue)` pushes an item to the front of an array.